# Charset problems with PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem with a PHP code that transforms accent characters in non accent characters. I have this code working a year ago but I'm trying to get this to work but without success. The translation is not done correctly.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

echo accentdestroyer('azeméis');

    /**
     * 
     * This function transform accent characters to non accent characters
     * @param text $string
     */
    function accentdestroyer($string) {
        $string=strtr($string,
        "()!$?: ,&+-/.ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ"
        ,
        "-------------SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy");

        return $string;
    }

?>
```

I have tested to save the document in UTF-8 but gives me something like this: "azemy�is"

Some clues on what can I do to get this working correctly?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution may be to [*transliterate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) those characters automatically using [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

As for the reason your function doesn't work, it may have something to do with the fact that `echo strlen('Š');` outputs 2. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) explicitly refers to *single byte characters*.

Also,

```
$a = 'Š';

var_dump(strtr('Š', 'Š', '!')); // string(2) "!�"
```

So the first byte has been matched but the second one (leftover) isn't a byte pointing to a valid Unicode character.

#### Update

Here is a workign example using `iconv()`.

```
$str = 'ŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚ';
 
$str = iconv("utf-8", "us-ascii//TRANSLIT", $str); 
 
var_dump($str); // string(37) "OEZsoezY?uAAAAAAAECEEEEIIII?NOOOOO?UU"
```

Some characters didn't quite translate, such as `¥` and `Ø`, but most did. You can append `//IGNORE` to the output character set to silently discard the ones which don't transliterate.

You could also drop all non word characters too using a [Unicode regex](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) with `\pL`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tested iconv() but without success. What should I do get this characters without accents? Best Regards,

Comment: No, `\pL` **is not word characters**.  It is only letters!!  Besides mere *Letters*, [word characters in Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) include all *Letter Numbers*, all *Connector Punctuation*, all *Marks*, and all *Other Alphabetics*.

Comment: @tchrist Wouldn't `\PL` be the not matching? Cheers.

Comment: The assertion was that you could use `\pL` to find all non-word characters.  You cannot.